# kivy settings: pythonic way of dealing with list of values

Tags: python, kivy

I am building an App which controls a pH robot (based on the [kivy crashcourse](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oQdGWeN51EE&list=PLdNh1e1kmiPP4YApJm8ENK2yMlwF1_edq&index=13) on youtube). The `build_config` function looks like:

```
def build_config(self, config):
    '''
    This function defines the items (like buttons etc.) and their default values. The type, title and description of these items if defined in the file settingsjson.py For each config.setdefault dictionary a json_panel is added in the function build_settings.
    '''
    config.setdefaults(
        'general',
        {'pH_1': False,
        'pH_2': False,
        'pH_3': False,
        'pH_4': False,
        'response_time': 10,
        'base_concentration': 5000,
        'data_path': '/home/moritz/data/'
        })
    config.setdefaults(
        'pump',
        {'some': True 
        })
    config.setdefaults(
        'experiment',
        {'volume_1': 100,
         'volume_2': 100,
         'volume_3': 100,
         'volume_4': 100,
         'buffer_1': 25,
         'buffer_2': 25,
         'buffer_3': 25,
         'buffer_4': 25
        })
```

Currently I hardcoded four pH-probes. In the future it should be possible to define the number of probes and according to that the settings panels should change (1-8 probes, dynamically). Regardless if the number of probes is hardcoded or not, I end up with individual values. Later on, I do have to convert them to an array.

The idea is to pass `self.config.items` to the program which does the pH-control part and convert the items similar to (pseudocode):

```
for key in items('general'):
    pH_probes = [item[key].value for key in items('general') if key.startswith('pH')]
```

However, that doesn`t seem very clever, since I do have to make sure that the values are in order (1-4). How can this be done in a better way ?

Based on the accepted answer I came up with following solution:

```
def get_config_values(self,section, variable):
    '''
    This section returns  a list of the individual config values for a defined variable for the specified section (e.g 'pH' in section 'general')
    '''
    # get the dictionary for the specified section
    cdict = dict(self.config.items(section))

    # iterate over the keys in the config dictionary, return value if key startswith variable
    # sort them by the last value after the underscore and return a list of the values 
    sorted_list = sorted([value for key, value in d.iteritems() if key.startswith(variable)], key = lambda x: int(x.split('_')[-1]) )
    return sorted_list
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could first form the list with just `pH keys` and then sort the list

**Code:**

```
dic = {'general':
        {'pH_1': False,
        'pH_2': False,
        'pH_3': False,
        'pH_4': False,
        'response_time': 10,
        'base_concentration': 5000,
        'data_path': '/home/moritz/data/'
        }}
[dic['general'][val] for val in sorted([value for value in dic["general"] if value.startswith("pH")],key = lambda x:int(x[3:]) )]
```

**Output:**

```
[False, False, False, False]
```